# Php relating two IDs

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im doing a schoolproject which is creating a simple guestbook. (Im beginner) I am stuck on how to relate two id's with each other. I have two different database tables one called guestbook for storing the post's, and one called members for storing the registered members.

Now what i need to do is to relate the PostID with the UserID so you can see who wrote which post. Right now  when a member logs on it says that all posts was written by that user and if i log on with another user it says that that user has written all the posts.

This is my code for the home.php file which contains the guestbook i also have a guestbookuservalidation file which i can post if you need it?

```
    <?php
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
if($_SESSION['login'] == 1)     //om sessionen är 1 så

{
echo "<h1>Välkommen till gästboken $username</h1>";




 // Connect to the database
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
 mysql_select_db("guestbookdatabase");

//******************************************************************//
//Form and add stuff

echo "<h2>Posta till Gästboken</h2>
<form action='home.php' method='post'>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Titel:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='titel' style='width: 300px;'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Inlägg:</td>
<td><textarea name='inlägg' style='width: 300px; height: 100px;'></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type='submit' name='postknapp' value='Posta'</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>";





//******************************************************************//
//Display stuff
echo "<h2>Nuvarande Poster</h2>";

if ($_POST['postknapp']) {

$title = strip_tags($_POST['titel']);
$message = strip_tags($_POST['inlägg']);

if ($title && $message) {

    //Lägg till i databasen
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO guestbook (Title,Post) VALUES ('$title','$message')");

    echo "Ditt inlägg har lagts till i gästboken!"; 

}
else

echo "Du har inte fyllt i nödvändig information för att kunna göra ett inlägg.";

}

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guestbook ORDER BY PostID DESC");
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE Username = $username");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows > 0){

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
    $id = $row['PostID'];
    $name = $sql;
    $title = $row['Title'];
    $message = $row['Post'];
    $date = $row['Timestamp'];

    $message = nl2br($message);

    echo "<div> 
    Av <b>$name</b> vid <b>$date</b><br /> 
    <h2>$title</h2> <p>
    $message
    </div> <hr />";

}

}
else
echo "Inga inlägg hittades.";




//*****************************************************************//

mysql_close();



?>

<a href="logga_ut.php">Logga ut</a>





<?php

}
else // om session inte är 1 så 
{
echo "Du har INTE tillåtelse till gästboken! Klicka på länken för att logga in!";
?>
<p>
<br/><a href="index.html">Till login >></a>
<?php   
}

?>
```

Comment: Your guestbook table should have a column which is supposed to be a reference to the user id column in the user table. Whenever someone writes in that guestbook the id of the user writing in it should be stored in the user id column of the guestbook table.

But I don't see why someone should have to log in to write in a guestbook..

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Ok you think you could show me an example in php code not in creating a new column since i know how to do that? The log in system isn't really neccesary but it was our teacher that wanted it to include a log in system for a higher grade.

Answer (score 1):

In your database the `Members` table should have the following two columns:

1. id
2. name (you can break this down into 2 columns for first and last names if you like)

Then in the `Messages` table, you need to have:

1. id
2. memberId
3. message

When a *member* posts a *message*, you need to store this member's id in the Messages table along with the message.

Then, you can easily filter messages by memberId(s). Your query would look somewhat as follows:

`SELECT Members.name, Messages.message FROM Members JOIN Messages WHERE Messages.memberId = Member.id ORDER BY PostID DESC`

Comment: Because your table is called "members" you should not prefix all columns with "member" and instead call the table `members` and have the columns `id` and `name`

Comment: I only need the posts to display the correct Username that wrote them. The posts are already sorted by showing the newest post at top.

Comment: @WilliamBergendahl: Ok, I have updated my query for that purpose.

Comment: I wasn't sure so i have edited my query. This one should work. Please test this query first in a mysql client, because I haven't tested it. But, if this one works in a client it should work in mysql_*

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points. If you are doing this for a school project, I would absolutely not use `mysql_*` functions.  These are deprecated, and if I was grading you would fail you automatically for using them. I would suggest looking at `mysqli_*` functions which are similar in usage to the `mysql_*` counterparts.

Second, you are not doing anything to protect against SQL injection.  Again if I were grading you, I would fail you, because you just compromised the database.

Finally, what you are looking to do is use a JOIN condition in your query.  I don't know enough about your table structure, so you might need to adjust this example:

```
SELECT *
FROM guestbook
INNER JOIN members ON members.MemberID = guestbook.MemberID <-- use whatever your member id fileds are in the two tables here
WHERE members.Username = ?
ORDER BY guestbook.PostID DESC
```

Comment: This of course will only work if your `guestbook` table contains the author id. Edit: +1 for mysql_* notice. Everybody seem to miss the big red box.

Comment: Our teacher is using mysql_* functions i didnt even know about mysqli_* functions until now.. Inside my table members all i have there is UserID, Username, Userpassword.  In my guestbook table i now have PostID, Title, Post, Timestamp, UserID.

Answer (score 1):

be sure

- in your query where you generates the messages to add `WHERE id = '$userid'`
  so that the messages will be generated just for that user.

  - consider if you are new to `MYSQL` to change to `PDO` or `MYSQLI` ,